# Onsen UI, add a clear input button

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I can't find an easy way to add a clear (x) button to an input field in Onsen UI. Any help would be appreciated specifically for input type search.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using straight JS with the DOM, use this:

```
<input id="txtSearch" value="Clear Me">
<ons-button onclick="document.getElementById('txtSearch').value='';">Clear</ons-button>
```

Edit:  Adding another down and dirty solution, using simple CSS for this:

```
<input id="txtSearch" value="Clear Me">
<ons-icon icon="ion-close" size="20px" fixed-width="true" style="margin-left:-25px" onclick="document.getElementById('txtSearch').value='';"></ons-icon>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that put the button inside the input and not beside/below it...

Comment: Edited to add what you seek.  You might have to play with your css a bit, but this is the quickest and easiest way to do this without going into a bunch of bootstrap for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that the input of type search, you need to enable the x clear button using CSS because it's disabled in the onsen-ui styling. To enable it, add this line to your css

```
.search-input::-webkit-search-cancel-button { display: inline-block; }
```